# Computation of concordant and discordant pairs

Tags: r, performance

I would like to compute the number of concordant and discordant pairs of two large vectors. This function is a nice try, and works quite efficiently.

```
pairs <- function(x,y){
    n <- length(x)
    ix <- order(x)
    x <- x[ix]
    y <- y[ix]
    Nc <- sum(sapply(1:(n-1),function(i) sum(x[i]<x[(i+1):n] & y[i]<y[(i+1):n])))
    Nd <- sum(sapply(1:(n-1),function(i) sum(x[i]<x[(i+1):n] & y[i]>y[(i+1):n])))
    return(list(Nc=Nc,Nd=Nd))
}

x <- runif(10000)
y <- runif(10000)
system.time(pairs(x,y))
```

Do you have any idea on how it would be possible to boost the function?

Comment: Check [ConDis.matrix function from asbio package](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/asbio/html/ConDis.matrix.html)

Comment: You've already sorted `x` right? So you don't need to calculate `x[i]<x[(i+1):n]`? Removing this calculation will half your computation time (through my testing).

Comment: It's a clever idea, and will work with the aforementioned example, but let's imagine we have some ties in the data, `x <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace = T);y <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace = T)`. In this case the number of concordant and discordant pairs would be not correctly counted.

Comment: @And Removing dupes for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of operations are tough to vectorize because you need to compare every element to all later elements. If the counting operation is a performance bottleneck in your code, then one possibility would be to implement it in C++ using the Rcpp package:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
  "IntegerVector CDcount(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
    IntegerVector counts(2, 0);
    int n = x.size();
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
      for (int j=i+1; j < n; ++j) {
        counts[0] += (x[i] < x[j]) && (y[i] < y[j]);
        counts[1] += (x[i] < x[j]) && (y[i] > y[j]);
      }
    }
    return counts;
  }")

pairs2 <- function(x, y) {
  n <- length(x)
  ix <- order(x)
  x <- x[ix]
  y <- y[ix]
  counts <- CDcount(x, y)
  return(list(Nc=counts[1], Nd=counts[2]))
}
```

For your test data, this results in a 50 times speedup on my system.

```
x <- runif(10000)
y <- runif(10000)
system.time(pairs(x,y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.892   1.447   6.584 
system.time(pairs2(x, y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.119   0.001   0.120 
identical(pairs(x, y), pairs2(x, y))
# [1] TRUE
```

The Rcpp package takes some time to compile the `CDcount` function, so this option is probably only helpful if you are operating on very large vectors or if you are repeating the operation many times.